# Confusion with partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $y=e^{t^2/2}$, so $\frac{dy}{dt}=yt$. Then $\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t\partial y}=t$, although this would contradict $\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial y\partial t}=\frac{\partial 1}{\partial t}=0$ (and also the actual value $t+\frac1t$)

Where did I go wrong and what's the proper way to take the partial derivative with respect to $y$?

Comment: You are mixing $y$ *function* with $y$ *variable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$y'=y(t)t$$

thus

$$\frac{\partial y'}{\partial y}=t+y\frac{d t}{d y}=t+\frac1t$$

I'm not completely sure that take this kind of partial derivative has a meaning but note that

$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}1=0$$

$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}te^{t^2/2}=0$$

Note also that

$$\frac{\partial y'(y,t)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\neq\frac{\partial^2y(t)}{\partial t\partial y}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial y(t)}{\partial y}$$

since the LHS is a first order partial derivative on $y'(y,t)$ while the RHS is a second order partial derivative on $y(t)$.

Comment: So why are the other two partial derivatives wrong?

Comment: Could you please clarify better what do you mean with $\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t\partial y}$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}}{\partial y}$ - Is this ill-defined?

Comment: @Akababa in any case we don't get a contradiction taking the second partial derivatives, I've added some detail.

Comment: So why isn't $\frac{\partial{y'}}{\partial{y}}\neq \frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t\partial y}$ a contradiction?

Comment: @Akababa I add something on that to clarify my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

If $y = e^{t^2/2}$ ($y$ function), $\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}$ does not makes sense because you are using the *same* name for *different* things.

$\frac{\partial(e^{t^2/2})}{\partial y}$ ($y$ variable) makes sense and is $= 0$.

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}$ ($y$ variable) makes sense and is $= 1$.

Comment: So it's not possible to take the derivative of both sides of $\frac{dy}{dt}=yt$ with respect to $y$?

Comment: @Akababa, *what* is the derivative with respect to a *function*?

Comment: well for example if I define it using chain rule $\frac{dz}{dy}=\frac{dz}{dt}/\frac{dy}{dt}$.

Comment: @Akababa, why do you expect that (your) $\frac{d}{dy} = $ (the usual) $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$? You **can't** use the same name for different things.